# Multiple Problems with Sed on Mac OS X

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

Using Mac OS X command line I want to perform a simple find and replace in a **large** number of files, within the current directory and its many sub-directories.

I need to perform many replacements so I'd like the script to be as performant as possible.

Whatever I try seems to result in some random error so I'm finally asking for help.

So given I have two variables:

```
FIND=oldText
REPLACE=newText
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g" *
> sed: Build: in-place edditing only works for regular expressions
```

Apparently this is trying to sed on directory path's itself so I subsequently tried (to exclude directories from being sed'ed)

```
find * -type f  -print | xargs sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g"
> xargs: sed: Argument list too long
```

So because I have such a large list of files to action xargs can't handle it. Apparently -exec is better at large lists..

```
find * -type f  -print -exec sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g" {} \;
```

Now this does actually work HOWEVER sed decides it must correct the missing eof/linefeed in all files in which they are missing, despite there being no replacements in the file.  Unfortuntely there are thousands of files of this nature and its not an option for me to be making changes of this magnitude for this current piece of work. (Please don't preach about how I should correct the files, thats not the question I am asking).

So in an attempt to overcome this issue I have tried to first extract the list of files that do indeed contain my ${FIND} term and then only perform the sed on those files...

```
grep -r -l -e "${FIND}" "." | sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g"
> sed: -i may not be used with stdin
```

-

```
grep -r -l -e "${FIND}" "." | -exec sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g" {} \;
> ./file1.txt: line 10: -exec: command not found
```

-

```
$( grep -r -l -e "${FIND}" "." ) -exec sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g" {} \;
> ./file1.txt: line 10: -exec: command not found
```

-

```
FILEPATHS_CONTAINING_FIND=$( grep -r -l -e "${FIND}" "." )
sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g" "${FILEPATHS_CONTAINING_FIND}"
> sed: ./File1.txt
./File2.txt
./File3.txt: No such file or directory
```

I think here the its treating the variable ${FILEPATHS_CONTAINING_FIND} as a single long file path. If I remove the double quotes "" it doesn't handle paths with spaces so that's not an option either.
Went back to trying xargs now that the list of files is shorter having filtered...

```
$( grep -r -l -e "${FIND}" "." ) | xargs sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g"
> ./Script.sh: line 10: ./File1.txt: Permission denied
```

Trying sudo in various places makes no difference.

Anyway I've resorted to using this for loop but I'd really rather something more succinct and performant.

```
IFS=$'\n' # Ensure spaces don't mess up the for loop
for FILEPATH_CONTAINING_FIND in $(grep -r -l -e "${FIND}" "."); do
    sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g" "${FILEPATH_CONTAINING_FIND}"
done
```

Can anyone help me with the problems I've experienced above?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `-i ''` to overwrite files while you still have not got your script working?  Overwriting files without backup should only be done when you're pretty confident the whole thing will work.  Well, never mind; they're your files — you can do as you please.  But sanity dictates that you don't (normally) go around overwriting files until you're sure you're going to do it right.

Comment: If you're going to use `-exec`, use `{} +` instead of `{} \;` because it makes `find` behave like `xargs` and run with multiple file names as arguments.  The error message `xargs: sed: Argument list too long` is pretty weird.  Exactly how long are your `${FIND}` and `${REPLACE}` strings?

Comment: The sequence of 4 commands after 'So in an attempt to overcome this issue' are bizarre.  They _should_ fail.  Do you have file names with spaces in them to deal with?  If not, then `grep -r -l … | xargs sed …` should deal with the files containing the match.  If you have spaces or other characters outside the portable file name character set in the names, say so.  It makes your job harder.  If you have file names containing newlines, it makes life even harder; that would be important information to have.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I use git so all the files are backed up and I can simply just reset my working copy in between attempts.  Thanks for your concern.

Comment: The ${FIND} and ${REPLACE} are exceptionally short in this case, general single digits no of chars.

Comment: Yes I need to be able to handle file names with spaces in the file name and path.

Comment: Thanks for your input so far :-)

Comment: As soon as you have spaces etc to deal with, raw `xargs` is not appropriate (it splits its input on white space).  You might need to look at `xargs -0` which expects file names terminated by a null byte; and you need to look at making sure the file name generator marks the ends of the file names with null bytes too (e.g.`find … -print0`). You've got a serviceable answer.  Most of your problems would, I think, occur on any system — they aren't all peculiar to Mac.

Comment: wrt `sed decides it must correct the missing eof/linefeed` - if your files do not have terminating linefeeds then they are not text files per the POSIX standard and so if you run any tool on them you are invoking undefined behavior and hoping for the best. Good luck with that ;-)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find + grep + sed` like this:

```
# cd to parent dir

while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
   grep -q "$FIND" "$file" &&
   sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g" "$file"
done < <(find . -type f  -print0)
```

- Using `print0` we generate null byte terminated filenames from `find` command
- Using `read -d ''` we make `read` delimit on null byte
- Using `grep -q` we make sure pattern `$FIND` is found in files before we run `sed`
- If `$FIND` is just a plain string then you may consider using `grep -F`

---

**EDIT:** You can improve your `for` loop by using `while` loop and `grep -r --null`:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
   sed -i '' "s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/g" "$file"
done < <(grep -lR --null "$FIND" .)
```

Comment: Is this better than the for loop I presented at the end?  Seems far more complex than that.

Comment: Yes it is better as `for` loop is error prone due to word splitting when filenames have space or some other glob character. May be instead of `find` we can use `grep -r` with `--null` option (let me know if you want me to provide that option as well.

Comment: There's one problem with `grep --null` — it isn't supported by the BSD `grep` on Mac OS X; it is a GNU `grep` extension.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's what I thought too but then I found on my OSX it is supported. I have `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` on OSX.

Comment: Ah; interesting.  A discrepancy between the program (which lists `--null` when you ask `grep --help`) and the man page (which only mentions null in the context "The caret `^' matches the null string").  Given a choice, one assumes the program's self-documentation is more accurate than the 'printed' documentation.  I live, I learn.

Comment: @EdMorton: :) Yes, I am familiar with views on `grep -r`. My original answer wasn't using `grep -r` at all, I just added because OP had attempted `for` loop using `grep -r` and I tried improving that in edited section. I would  recommend using `find` always.